# Simulating Pendulum Motion in Android

Tags: java, android, simulation

Quite sometime back I had written an Android application which simulates the path of a pendulum. You can also have look at the complete discussion in my technical blog [here](http://som-itsolutions.blogspot.in/2012/06/android-graphics-and-animation-pendulum.html).

Please review it and provide me with your valuable comments.

```
package com.somitsolutions.android.pendulamsimulation;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;

public class PendulamSimulationActivity extends Activity {

    //private Paint mPaint;
    private boolean leftToRightMovement = true;
    private boolean rightToLeftMovement = false;
    private boolean atTheMiddlePositionWhileLeftToRight = false;
    private boolean atTheMiddlePositionWhileRightToLeft = false;
    private boolean firstHalf = true;
    private boolean secondHalf = false;
    private volatile double ballX = 0;
    private volatile double ballY = 0;

    //private boolean theCenterBeingDrawn = false;

    double angleAccel = 0.0;
    double angleVelocity = 0;
    double dt = 0.15;

    private boolean flag = false;

    boolean flagCondition = false;

    private int anchorX;
    private int anchorY;
    public static double initialAngle = Math.PI/4;
    public static double angle = Math.PI/4;
    double angleInThePreviousStep = Math.PI/4;

    private static final int length = 150;

    private Paint mPaint;

    private Paint mRefreshPaint;

    //SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Panel p = new Panel(this);

        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

        mRefreshPaint = new Paint();
        mRefreshPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        setContentView(p);

    }

    class Panel extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback{


        public PendulamThread _thread;

        public Panel(Context context) {
            super(context);


            getHolder().addCallback(this);
            _thread = new PendulamThread(getHolder(), this);
        }

        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
                int height) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             _thread.setRunning(true);
             _thread.start();

        }

        public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             _thread.setRunning(false);

        }

        @Override
        public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

                canvas.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                anchorX = getWidth()/2;

                anchorY = getHeight()/4;

                //if(!theCenterBeingDrawn){
                canvas.drawCircle(anchorX - 3, anchorY - 4, 7, mPaint);



                //First Half ... Left To Right
                if(leftToRightMovement == true && rightToLeftMovement ==false && atTheMiddlePositionWhileLeftToRight == false && atTheMiddlePositionWhileRightToLeft == false && firstHalf == true && secondHalf == false){

                    angleInThePreviousStep = angle;

                    angle = angle - dt/Math.sqrt(length/9.81);



                    if(angle >0.01){
                        ballX = anchorX - (int)length*(Math.sin(angle));

                        ballY = anchorY + (int)length*(Math.cos(angle));

                        canvas.drawLine(anchorX, anchorY,(float)ballX,(float)ballY,mPaint);

                        canvas.drawCircle((float)ballX , (float)ballY , 14, mPaint );
                    }

                    else{
                        atTheMiddlePositionWhileLeftToRight = true;
                        atTheMiddlePositionWhileRightToLeft = false;
                        leftToRightMovement = true;
                        rightToLeftMovement = false;
                        firstHalf = false;
                        secondHalf = false;
                    }



                    return;

                }
                //First Half Left To Right end

                //AtTheMiddle while Left To right
                if(atTheMiddlePositionWhileLeftToRight == true && leftToRightMovement == true && rightToLeftMovement == false && atTheMiddlePositionWhileRightToLeft  == false && firstHalf ==false && secondHalf == false){

                    angle = 0;
                    angleInThePreviousStep = 0;
                    flag = true;
                    angleAccel = 0;
                    angleVelocity = (Math.sqrt(2*9.81*length));
                    ballX = anchorX;
                    ballY = anchorY + length;
                    canvas.drawLine(anchorX, anchorY,(float)ballX,(float)ballY,mPaint);

                    canvas.drawCircle((float)ballX ,(float)ballY , 14, mPaint );

                    atTheMiddlePositionWhileLeftToRight = false;
                    leftToRightMovement = true;
                    rightToLeftMovement = false;
                    atTheMiddlePositionWhileRightToLeft = false;
                    firstHalf = false;
                    secondHalf = true;


                    return;
                }
                //at the middle while left to right end

                //Left to Right second half
                if(leftToRightMovement == true && rightToLeftMovement == false && atTheMiddlePositionWhileLeftToRight == false && atTheMiddlePositionWhileRightToLeft ==false && firstHalf == false && secondHalf == true){

                    double velocityAtTheBeginning = angleVelocity;//not sure if doing the right thing... forgot mechanics


                    angle += dt/(Math.sqrt(length/9.81));


                    if((initialAngle- angle)>0.01){

                    ballX = anchorX + (int) (Math.sin(angle) * length); //greater than anchorX
                    ballY = anchorY + (int) (Math.cos(angle) * length);//less than anchorY

                    canvas.drawLine(anchorX, anchorY,(float)ballX,(float)ballY,mPaint);

                    canvas.drawCircle((float)ballX , (float)ballY , 14, mPaint );

                    }
                    else{
                        atTheMiddlePositionWhileLeftToRight = false;
                        leftToRightMovement = false;
                        rightToLeftMovement = true;
                        atTheMiddlePositionWhileRightToLeft = false;
                        firstHalf = true;
                        secondHalf = false;
                        angle = initialAngle;
                    }
                    return;
                }

                //left to right second half end

                ////right to left first half
                if(leftToRightMovement == false && rightToLeftMovement ==true && atTheMiddlePositionWhileLeftToRight == false && atTheMiddlePositionWhileRightToLeft == false && firstHalf == true && secondHalf == false){

                    angleInThePreviousStep = angle;

                    angle = angle - dt/Math.sqrt(length/9.81);



                    if(angle >0.01){
                        ballX = anchorX + (int)length*(Math.sin(angle));

                        ballY = anchorY + (int)length*(Math.cos(angle));

                        canvas.drawLine(anchorX, anchorY,(float)ballX,(float)ballY,mPaint);

                        canvas.drawCircle((float)ballX , (float)ballY , 14, mPaint );
                    }

                    else{
                        atTheMiddlePositionWhileLeftToRight = false;
                        atTheMiddlePositionWhileRightToLeft = true;
                        leftToRightMovement = false;
                        rightToLeftMovement = true;
                        firstHalf = false;
                        secondHalf = false;
                    }

                    return;

                }

                //Right to left first half end


                ///at the middle while right to left
                if(atTheMiddlePositionWhileLeftToRight == false && leftToRightMovement == false && rightToLeftMovement == true && atTheMiddlePositionWhileRightToLeft  == true && firstHalf ==false && secondHalf == false){

                    angle = 0;
                    //angleInThePreviousStep = 0;
                    //flag = true;
                    angleAccel = 0;
                    angleVelocity = (Math.sqrt(2*9.81*length));
                    ballX = anchorX;
                    ballY = anchorY + length;
                    canvas.drawLine(anchorX, anchorY,(float)ballX,(float)ballY,mPaint);

                    canvas.drawCircle((float)ballX ,(float)ballY , 14, mPaint );

                    atTheMiddlePositionWhileLeftToRight = false;
                    leftToRightMovement = false;
                    rightToLeftMovement = true;
                    atTheMiddlePositionWhileRightToLeft = false;
                    firstHalf = false;
                    secondHalf = true;


                    return;
                }
                //at the middle while right to left end




                ///Right to left second half
                if(leftToRightMovement == false && rightToLeftMovement == true && atTheMiddlePositionWhileLeftToRight == false && atTheMiddlePositionWhileRightToLeft ==false && firstHalf == false && secondHalf == true){

                    double velocityAtTheBeginning = angleVelocity;//not sure if doing the right thing... forgot mechanics


                    angle += dt/(Math.sqrt(length/9.81));


                    if((initialAngle - angle)>0.01){

                    ballX = anchorX - (int) (Math.sin(angle) * length); //greater than anchorX
                    ballY = anchorY + (int) (Math.cos(angle) * length);//less than anchorY

                    canvas.drawLine(anchorX, anchorY,(float)ballX,(float)ballY,mPaint);

                    canvas.drawCircle((float)ballX , (float)ballY , 14, mPaint );

                    }
                    else{
                        atTheMiddlePositionWhileLeftToRight = false;
                        leftToRightMovement = true;
                        rightToLeftMovement = false;
                        atTheMiddlePositionWhileRightToLeft = false;
                        firstHalf = true;
                        secondHalf = false;
                        angle = initialAngle;
                    }
                    return;
                }        
        }

    }//onDraw


    /////
    class PendulamThread extends Thread {
        private SurfaceHolder _surfaceHolder;
        private Panel _panel;
        private boolean _run = false;

        public PendulamThread(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Panel panel) {
            _surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
            _panel = panel;
        }

        public void setRunning(boolean run) {
            _run = run;
        }

        public SurfaceHolder getSurfaceHolder() {
            return _surfaceHolder;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Canvas c;
            while (_run) {
                c = null;
                try {
                    c = _surfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                    synchronized (_surfaceHolder) {
                        _panel.onDraw(c);
                        Thread.sleep(50);
                       //c.drawColor(Color.BLACK);
                       // _panel.postInvalidateDelayed(10);
                    }
                }
                 catch(InterruptedException e){

                 }

                finally {
                }
                    // do this in a finally so that if an exception is thrown
                    // during the above, we don't leave the Surface in an
                    // inconsistent state
                    if (c != null) {
                        _surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

    }


    /////
```

Answer (score 5):

#### Boolean usage:

You have waaay too many explicit boolean flags, which are only a implicit variant of some others.

> ```
> private boolean leftToRightMovement = true;
> private boolean rightToLeftMovement = false;
> private boolean atTheMiddlePositionWhileLeftToRight = false;
> private boolean atTheMiddlePositionWhileRightToLeft = false;
> private boolean firstHalf = true;
> private boolean secondHalf = false;
> ```

This clutters your code extremely, especially in your `onDraw()` method. Keep it simple and just do the following:

```
private boolean leftToRightMovement = true;
private boolean isAtMiddlePosition = false;
private boolean isInFirstHalf = true;
```

All other booleans can be achieved by combining these three:

```
rightToLeftMovement = !leftToRightMovement;
atTheMiddlePositionWhileLeftToRight = leftToRightMovement && isAtMiddlePosition;
atTheMiddlePositionWhileRightToLeft = !leftToRightMovement && isAtMiddlePosition;
secondHalf = !isInFirstHalf;
```

**Comparing and concatenating booleans**
You check your booleans against boolean values. That doesn't make sense. Compare these statments who are equal in result:

```
boolValue == true  --> boolValue
boolValue == false --> !boolValue
```

#### Commenting:

You have lots of Todo comments left in your code, if you don't need to do anything anymore they are pure clutter, utterly useless and should be removed.

> ```
> //First Half ... Left to Right
> if(leftToRightMovement == true && rightToLeftMovement ==false && atTheMiddlePositionWhileLeftToRight == false && atTheMiddlePositionWhileRightToLeft == false && firstHalf == true && secondHalf == false){
> ```

This comment (and all the other ones, that are so similar) is not helpful. If you reduce the number of bools you use, you have exactly that, written in your code. This makes your comment noise. It should be removed. Then your if-statement looks like this:

```
if(leftToRightMovement && firstHalf && !atMiddlePosition){
```

You can do the same with almost all the if-statements you have in your `onDraw()`